# Deducing the mechanical power necessary for generating voltage in a loop wire

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electromagnetic-induction

From what I've learned, it seems that by rotating a loop wire inside a magnetic field we can create what's called electromotive force, which can be thought of an analogue to voltage, and it corresponds to the work a single charge will do if it travels around the loop.

Faraday's law gives the relationship that the voltage is proportional to the rate of change of the flux going through the loop.

Power is not mentioned anywhere, so this almost make think that this means we can simply use a fixed amount of mechanical power to spin a wire, and this gives us a fixed amount of voltage, independent of the wire and its resistance, meaning the output power can actually vary, depending on the resistance.

But I expect that's wrong, and it could be the opposite - assuming power in equals power out, then based on the resistance of the wire we might actually need different amounts of mechanical power.

So as an example, it would seem that if we simply lower the resistance of the wire, we will actually need to apply more mechanical power to get the same voltage. Assuming the mechanical power source that rotates the loop moves at a fixed angular velocity, this means there will actually have to be more torque as we lower the resistance of the wire. Is this correct?

Related to the above - as the loop rotates inside the magnetic field (assuming it's a uniform constant field), the rate at which the flux changes is not constant, so the voltage in the loop can vary. Will the required torque lower when the rate of change of the magnetic flux lowers?

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain this in terms of an induction motor, but principally this works in reverse for a generator (which is fundamentally what your question seems to be asking).

Faraday's law of induction is restated in electrical engineering terms as,

$$v(t) = L\frac{di(t)}{dt}$$

Where $L$ is the inductance of the material. This parameter accounts for the number of turns of wire (in the case of a wound inductor) as well as the magnetic flux. The magnetic flux will be proportional to the amount of current flowing through the element so we see current replacing $\Phi_B(t)$.

The above equation explains the voltage and current relationship for a circuit involving an inductor, and is the primary mechanism which explains how power is transferred to the rotor of an induction or synchronous motor, via an air gap.

More or less, there is power transferred from the motor to the stator via induction, and the power is calculated in the stator circuit in the typical way:

$$p(t)=v(t)i(t)$$

In practice, this calculation is done using [phasors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) to simplify the differential equations into algebraic ones.

Further, the model of an induction motor is simplified so that the only practical calculation is the amount of power absorbed by a resistive circuit element $R_r'/s$, where $s$ is the induction motor's slip (basically the different between the physical rotation speed of the motor and the rotation of the magnetic field).

The [Steinmetz equivalent circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_motor#Steinmetz_equivalent_circuit) is typically used to model induction motors, and so we can see how this power transfer is practically modeled. We can see winding losses in the stator, and the power which is transferred to the rotor is converted to mechanical power (also with some loss of power through the air gap).

Edit: I didn't specifically answer your hypotheticals about lowering resistance, effect on torque, etc., but here are some more equations that might help clarify some things:

The power that is transferred through the air gap to the rotor (in phasors):
$$P_r' = I_r'^2 \frac{R_r'}{s}$$

The $'$ shows that these quantities are referred to the primary side (more electrical engineering calculation tricks; you can search per unit calculations if interested).

By current division,

$$I_r' = \frac{jX_m}{R'_r/s + j(X_r' + X_m)}I_s$$

So the current depends primarily on the stator current and the slip, which makes sense as per the original discussion regarding induction.

The mechanical power which the rotor can use:

$$P_m = P_r' - P_{loss} = \tau \omega$$